# Mouse shortcut for Paste (CMD + V) does not work on password fields

Tags: macos, copy-paste, logitech-mouse

I have a bluetooth Logitech M720 mouse with the tilt buttons assigned for COPY (CMD+C) and PASTE(CMD+V). This works perfectly except when I am pasting into password fields. It does not paste the copied text into any password fields (tried all browsers, from the latest Chrome to Safari). However, if I paste it using my keyboard it works. Using MacOS 10.14.3

Wondering if this is a MacOS restriction or some browser standard?

Comment: So you're certain it copies, from anywhere, even from the browser? What browser? if the answer is Chrome [which it always seems to be when something non-standard happens] test Safari. Also check your Logitech control panel has that action assigned to all apps.

Comment: Tried Safari, Firefox and Chrome with same results. I can copy text from anywhere and paste anywhere in the browser except for password input fields. I have set it to ALL apps in Logitech Options panel.

Comment: tbh, I'd blame the logitech CP. My last Logitech mouse MX-518, I trashed their CP entirely & used SteerMouse instead - much more flexible & reliable. Unfortunately I now have a new Logi  MXMaster2 which doesn't report its functionality correctly to the OS, so I'm stuck using theirs [& it sucks] :\

Comment: Same issue. I had fixed it somehow on 1Password v7 but since upgrading to v8 it is broken again and I don't remember what I did to fix it last time.

Comment: Same issue. MxMaster2, all browsers and desktop applications with a password field. Does not matter where the password was copied from, that always works. The pasting will not.
This is an Apple security feature.

Answer (score 0):

In short, use SteerMouse.

I have a Logitech G502 Hero and it's configured using Logitech G Hub. When I have a password field in focus in a browser (Firefox, in my case), not only can I not paste into it using the mouse button I assigned for that, but none of the other mouse button assignments work either, only the default primary, secondary, and middle clicks.

For instance, two of my mouse button assignments switch to the next tab and the previous tab, but if I click on a password field so that it's in focus, I can't use those buttons to switch tabs. Logitech, for whatever reason, does not want custom mouse button assignments to work when a password field is in focus. Back when I used SteerMouse, this wasn't an issue.